# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 (and 16.04, 16.10 Unity) freezes on reboot if put on sleep

Tags: gnome, swap, reboot, 17.04

My laptop freezes when asked to reboot if it was previously put on sleep (by closing the laptop). I am using Ubuntu 17.04 (Gnome) but I've had this issue also with Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity) and Ubuntu 16.10 (Unity).

I don't have this problem with my desktop so I think this is somehow ASUS related. My laptop is an ASUS X556UJ.

I've the perception that the problem somehow lies with the swap partition but I don't have the knowledge to properly debug the system and when it freezes I can't even press ESC to see the output (I know this is asked to debug the problem).

The laptop has 16GB memory but only 8GB are recognised by Ubuntu (as side question, do you know why?). The swap partition is of 12GB.

In particular, this is the output of $ sudo lshw | grep product:

```
product: X556UJ (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
   product: X556UJ
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
         product: HMT451S6CFR6A-PB
         product: M471B5173EB0-YK0
      product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
         product: HD Graphics 520
         product: Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem
         product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            product: xHCI Host Controller
               product: USB2.0-CRW
               product: USB Camera
            product: xHCI Host Controller
         product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
         product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
         product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
         product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
         product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         product: Intel Corporation
            product: GK208M [GeForce 920M]
         product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
         product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
            product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
         product: Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
         product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
         product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
         product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
         product: HFS512G32MND-321
         product: DVD A  DA8AESH
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution at last.

The following steps fixed the issue for ASUS X556UJ with Intel/Nvidia:

1. Edit your grub configuration:

   `sudo vi /etc/default/grub` and change the contents of the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
   ```
2. Edit your Nvidia settings:

   ```
   nvidia-settings
   ```

   Select PRIME Profiles

   Select Intel